# Why doesn't infection with Clostridium Tetani immunize you?

Tags: immunology, bacteriology

[What Immunity to COVID-19 Really Means - Scientific American](https://www.scientificamerican.com/article/what-immunity-to-covid-19-really-means/)

> It is less clear what those antibody tests mean for real life, however, because immunity functions on a continuum. With some pathogens, such as the [varicella-zoster virus](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC2722564/) (which causes chicken pox), infection confers near-universal, long-lasting resistance. Natural infection with *Clostridium tetani,* the [bacterium](https://www.who.int/news-room/fact-sheets/detail/tetanus) that causes tetanus, on the other hand, offers no protection—and even people getting vaccinated for it require regular booster shots. On the extreme end of this spectrum, individuals infected with [HIV](https://www.sciencedaily.com/releases/2009/04/090422151832.htm) often have large amounts of antibodies that do nothing to prevent or clear the disease.

[Clostridium Tetani - StatPearls - NCBI Bookshelf](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/books/NBK482484/)

> It should be noted that infection with *C. tetani* does not provide immunity, and thus, all patients with the diagnosis of tetanus should receive immunization immediately with three doses of tetanus and diphtheria toxoid.

Comment: What research have you done to try to answer this question yourself? The top hit when I searched with "Clostridium-tetani immunity" was [this book chapter](https://www.asmscience.org/content/book/10.1128/9781555815905.ch52) ...

Comment: @tyersome That abstract doesn't answer my question? That book chapter is pay-walled.

Comment: Interestingly if I do the search I suggested and click on the link to that article I can see a preview of the first two pages, but if I go directly following the link I can't see it either ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a big difference with tetanus compared with other infections. The amount of toxin that produces tetany is extremely tiny. Even a small infection that the immune system has yet to react to can be lethal.
To produce a long-lasting response against the **bacterium** would require a lethal number of bacteria.

Vaccination with the toxoid results in antibodies against the toxin, not the bacteria.

Comment: The problem is different: Tetanus toxin is so supertoxic that the amount needed to poison you is so small that this is not enough to trigger an immune response.